# Perl partial match

Tags: perl

Please consider the script below, I want to match $b to $a even if $b is a partial match.
Can this done be done?

```
$a="MCF-7";
$b="MCF";
if($b=~m/$a/i)
{
    print "FOUND";
}
```

Comment: Can't you just reverse the sense?  `print "FOUND" if $a =~ /$b/i;` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While regular expressions can do this, it sounds like your problem could also be solved with the `index` function:

```
say index($haystack, $needle) >= 0 ? 'match' : 'fail'; # any position
say index($haystack, $needle) == 0 ? 'match' : 'fail'; # anchored at start
```

The `index` function is case sensitive.  If you want an insensitive match, apply the `uc` or `lc` function to both arguments.

Although the `index` function will be much faster than a regex, if you do want a regex solution you can build a regex generator that produces a series of alternations that will perform partial matching.

```
sub build_partial {
    my ($str, $min) = (@_, 1);
    my @re;
    for (0 .. length($str) - $min) {
        my $str = substr $str, $_;
        for ($min .. length $str) {
            push @re, quotemeta substr $str, 0, $_
        }
    }
    my $re = join '|' => sort {length $a <=> length $b} @re;
    qr/^(?:$re)$/i
}

my $haystack = 'MCF-7';
my $needle   = 'MCF';

my $regex = build_partial $haystack;

say $needle =~ /$regex/ ? 'match' : 'fail'; # match
```

The regex generated for `MCF-7` looks like this:

```
/^(?:M|C|F|7|MC|CF|\-|MCF|F\-|\-7|CF\-|F\-7|MCF\-|CF\-7|MCF\-7)$/i
```

And it will match even if the needle is a single character from the haystack.  `build_partial` takes an optional number indicating the minimum length required for a match:

```
my $regex_3 = build_partial $haystack, 3;
```

which produces this regex:

```
/^(?:MCF|CF\-|F\-7|MCF\-|CF\-7|MCF\-7)$/i
```

These patterns match a substring starting from any position.  If you want it anchored to the front of the string, `build_partial` gets a bit simpler:

```
sub build_partial {
    my ($str, $min) = (@_, 1);

    my $re = join '|' => map {
        quotemeta substr $str, 0, $_
    } $min .. length $str;

    qr/^(?:$re)$/i
}
```

Comment: I like the approach, though I wonder why you use `join '|' =>` instead of `join '|' ,`.

Comment: @flesk => just personal coding preference.  I tend to use the fat arrow any time that it draws a useful relationship between the arguments.  so `join ' ' => @list` but not `push @array => @list` since that is backwards

Answer (score 7):

You seem to have `$a` and `$b` mixed up:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $a="MCF-7";
my $b="MCF";
if($a=~/$b/i) #tests for case-insensitive matching of $b within $a.
{
 print "Found\n";
}
```

The code in your question produced no output since there's no match of `"MCF-7"` within `"MCF"`.